# How to optimize database design?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, relational-database

I am working on an ecommerce app. This app will have login/signup with phone no. only.
My partner does not want to create user without mobile verification. To avoid duplicate data in the database if a user doesn't proceed with OTP verification.

My aproach is to create user table and user otp table.

```
users:
    id
    name,
    phone,
    email 

user_resources:
    id,
    user_id(foreign key),
    otp
```

so as you can see otp cannot be create without a user_id.

The other idea is to create everything seprate like below. I think this design is more prone to false database. It will be defficult to create database reports.

```
users:
    id
    name,

# only two columns in users table

user_resources:
    id,
    user_id(users table),
    otp
    
verify_phone:
    user_id(foreign key users)
    phone
    is_phone_verified

verify_email:
    user_id(foreign key users)
    email
    is_email_verified
```

Is the second approach good?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by false database--but my preference would be to put all these fields in one table. I don't see a ton of value in such skinny tables.

Comment: you are not allowing duplicate accounts right ? so why not just use phonenumner or email to reference user instead of ids.